# Simulate a time interval

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a homework project where I need to simulate a time interval (4 minutes specifically) with the python time library.

I have to use the time.time() function, so I tried with that function but It only returns the seconds since the epoch.

Comment: It's always helpful to show the code you have tried in your question.

Comment: "simulate a time interval" - if you used e.g. `time.sleep` for perhaps four minutes that wouldn't _simulate_ an interval of four minutes, it would _actually_ delay four minutes. _simulating_ a time interval might be different from an actual delay/sleep. Which do you want?

Comment: i need to simulate a time interval, not delay the program.

Comment: In that case it is unlikely that you should use the time module except at the start (to decide the start time), because what you need to do is *not* otherwise linked to "real" time. What is this _simulation_ supposed to achieve - what is supposed to happen or be processed during/after this simulated delay of four minutes?

Comment: I need to enter data of cars, and after the 4 minutes do some statistics with that data

Comment: By „after 4 minutes“ do you mean real time has passed, or simulated time? If the former case, what part of time do you actually need to be simulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to simulate `time.sleep()`?

Without giving the answer away completely, consider the following usage of `time.time()`:

```
>>> import time
>>> start = time.time()
>>> time.time() - start
12.311654090881348
```

Between the time when the second and third commands were executed, it took me ~12.3 seconds.

Comment: i need to run my program for 4 minutes and after 4 minutes kill the program

Comment: Here's a hint: think about using a loop and using the technique above. If you need to exit the program you can use sys.exit().

Comment: i think i might have found a way

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.sleep(), which sleeps for the given amount of seconds. So time.sleep(5) would create a 5 second pause.

Answer (score 0):

`time.time()` gives you the time now expressed as seconds since the epoch. You want 4 minutes from now. So add 4 minutes. But you have to add seconds not minutes. So, `time.time() + 4 * 60`.